# Picasso not loading image from url in second activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to load an image from the first activity to my second activity, by passing it through an intent and then loading it with Picasso. However, even though the intent does work and the url is there, the image is not loading and I'm not sure why.
This is the second activity:

```
class PostActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPostBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post)
        binding = ActivityPostBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        //get title
        val detailTitle = intent.getStringExtra("NEWS_TITLE")
        binding.tvTitleItem.text = detailTitle

        //get image
        val detailImage = intent.getStringExtra("NEWS_IMAGE")
        Picasso.get().load(detailImage).into(binding.ivNewsImageDetail)

        binding.ivNewsImageDetail.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("IMAGE","$detailImage")
        }
```

Through the setOnClickListener is that I know the url is there but the spot is empty. Any ideas as to what is not working?

Comment: May I know what is the value of `detailImage` ?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine it's a jpg like this one https://bilder.bild.de/fotos/anders-breivik--ihn-nicht-zu-erschiessen-war-sehr-schwer-033ce064bf6a4970af469c557410fbe8-77154370/Bild/9.bild.jpg . This does work on the first activity so I'm not sure why it doesn't work here.

Comment: Share layout xml of PostActivity

Comment: I think problem is with your imageview  `ivNewsImageDetail`, Please share xml code

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the binding is not fully load. Try this.

```
binding.ivNewsImageDetail.post { 
   //get image
   val detailImage = intent.getStringExtra("NEWS_IMAGE")
   Picasso.get().load(detailImage).into(binding.ivNewsImageDetail)
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything sadly.. the image is still not loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
        Picasso.with(this).load(ImageUrl).into(imageView)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
```

}